# “undefined” error when checking “undefined” in an if statement

Tags: javascript

i'm new to javascript and i'm developing tetris game. i have written some piece of code and reused some code from other sites. But one of the function is causing me some problems and i'm  getting an error as "undefined is not an object evaluating board[y][x]". The piece of code is pasted below:

```
var COLS=10, ROWS=20;
var board = [];
function run() {
ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
for ( var x = 0; x < COLS; ++x ) {
    for ( var y = 0; y < ROWS; ++y ) {
        if ( board[ y ][ x ] ) {
            ctx.fillStyle = colors[ board[ y ][ x ] - 1 ];
            drawBlock( x, y );
        }
    }
}
}
```

i'm not understanding as why am i getting the error. i have tried executing it in both safari and IE 11 but the result is the same. i even tried using the typeof keyword in the if statement but there's no change. Could anyone please help me to get rid of this error.

thanks

Comment: You've initialized "board" as `[]`, but you're using it as if it's an array of objects (or arrays). Where is the code that puts values in the "board" array?

Comment: are you meaning `board[y][x]` to be `board[x][y]`

Comment: You need to check that the 1st dimension is not empty, as well. Change your condition to `board[y] && board[y][x]` to get at what you expected

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `board[ y ][ x ]` if you haven't initialised the `board` variable properly.
You are trying to execute next line:

```
board [0][0]
```

and what javascript would do, is, first it will try to get `board[0]` which will be `undefined`, then it will try to do `undefined[0]`, which will fire the error:

> undefined is not an object

You should first put some data into your `board` array, before running that loop.